# Array of Array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, dictionary, raspberry-pi

I need to create a very fast way to get to a list of objects and I am thinking that an array of an array of objects would work.  Perhaps there is a different way to do this so feel free to recommend an alternate implementation.

I have a group of objects that I need to group by a specified value.  Example, I would have a group of objects that need to be access by the number 10.  So I would find the group of object using the number 10 and then iterate over each object to perform tasks on each object.

```
10 - Object1, Object2, Object3
11 - Object4, Object5
```

I need to access these objects very fast that is why I was thinking an array of an array of objects.  I have looked into vector and maps but do not quite understand them completely.

I am using c++ on a raspberry pi with the g++ compiler.

Please let me know your thoughts and I thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you want such as `std::multimap<int, object>` or `std::unordered_multimap<int, object>`?

Comment: `multimap` are used is the key could repeat, in this case would be wasting `sizeof(key)` for every object of the key. Looking in the question if the key is in a range you could use `std::vector<std::vector<object>>>` (in every index of the outer vector would be the objects of that index, could use a base index to skips index if the range is for example 1000-2000, if the key are spread, use `std::map<int, std::vector<object>>`, the search of the object collection is **O(log keys)** and the iteration of the objects is cache friendly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a `std::set` for the group of objects.
2. Use a `std::map` to key in those groups.

This should work:

```
std::map<int, std::set<Object>> objects;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Array of Array of objects is often known as a matrix. You can imagine the matrix as a grid. This would be the fastest and most basic way to access all of your objects. To create a matrix declare it like below.

```
int matrix[10][10];
```

Now fill each spot of the matrix with an object

```
for(int row = 0; row<10;row++){
     for(int column = 0; column<10;column++){
          matrix[row][column] = Obj();
     }
}
```

Now that the matrix is filled you can access group 5 by a simple fast for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i<matrix[].length;i++){
   matrix[4] = _________
}
```

This would be the fastest and easiest way to attempt what you are doing. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I tried and this didn't work because I tried to add a object to an int array.  Am I doing something wrong?   matrix[row][column] = myObj();